# Why is my question too broad, and how can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795853/find-methods-with-modified-code-between-two-versions-of-a-java-class) on how to find methods with modified code between two versions of a Java class. The initial version came with too much background code (or at least that's what the one comment, from someone who didn't vote to close, told me) so I made significant edits to clean up and clarify the question.

Looking at the question timeline, it went through the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17656440) but it got three votes to leave closed. (In the queue, the edits look like a real mess, so maybe people weren't able to tell I had cleaned it up?)

I tried to make the question clearly state my goal in the first paragraph, how I tried to achieve it in the second section, and a clear example for ensuring that there is one correct answer in the last section.

What would be good approaches to improving the question to be narrow enough to obtain answers?

Comment: It is either a request for a tool (=off-topic), or (in case you want to write a code that does what you want) just a problem specification without any solution attempt (=too broad).

Comment: Ah, I've seen a number of questions for "how do I use diff to do x" or "does git diff have a flag like diff -p".  In my case, I tried diff and it seemed to have no flag to do what I needed and wondered if another tool would work.  Since I don't know another tool to work from, is that the problem so I need to be trying some specific tool?

Comment: The question has been reopened, but it now has one close vote. It begins again....

Comment: I guess one can never make everyone happy.  I've done my best it integrate all suggestions provided so far.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to add which *diff* tool you used for your first attempt (if I type diff on my commandline I get an error).

You could add one sentence at the end that asks:

> Can I find the modified methods with my *diff* tool or *git diff*  and if yes, how would I do that? (I'm not bound to those tools)

Or similar wording.

This will make clear you're not asking for a tool but for a solution to a problem you face with tools often used for programming tasks. But you're not ruling out getting a tool suggestion to solve your problem.

Comment: `diff` works on *my* terminal. Must be something wrong with yours.

Comment: @CodyGray subversion is not by default in my path ...